# Web Api Odata not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I created a Web Api OData controller and try to view it directly but it's not working.

WebApiConfig config

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
      config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "DefaultApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );
    }

    public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
      ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
      builder.EntitySet<Customer>("Customers");
      builder.Namespace = "PackageManager.Models";
      return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

in App start calling registering:

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

Api controller:

```
public class CustomersController : EntitySetController<Customer, string>
  {
    NorthwindDbContext _Context = new NorthwindDbContext();

    [Queryable]
    public override IQueryable<Customer> Get()
    {
      return _Context.Customers;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
      base.Dispose(disposing);
           _Context.Dispose();
    }
  }
```

Try to access :
localhost:2375/odata/Customers

then always getting error:

**The resource cannot be found.**

Comment: I looked over your code, and it looks absolutely fine to me. "The resource cannot be found" doesn't look like an error that Web API throws, so the request must not be making it to Web API at all. It might be IIS that isn't working for you. Is the folder attributed as an IIS application?

Comment: I didn't deployed on IIS, I am using vs iis express. Most interesting thing, first I added the Odata controller it's working fine. After that Install HOt Towel Single page application then it's not working. It tried many option but didn't work. Please suggest me if you have any other clue.

Comment: I have the exact same issue - were you able to solve this?

Comment: @t316 issue was with other controller configuration. so it's routed to other controller instead Api configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Just add follow to web.config on system.webServer\handler:

```
<add name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0" path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

or replace

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

to

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

(Different - one dot in path-attribute)

Answer (score -1):

@Parwej - Try writing the below code in your webapi.config instead of your code. Also make sure that proper case is followed in your URL as Odata url is case sensitive. And dont forget to use using System.Web.Http.OData instead of System.Web.Odata in controller. This should work.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
  ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
  builder.EntitySet<Customer>("Customers");
  config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
}
```